# Using links within PHP dropdown list

Tags: php, html, list

Hello I'm trying to learn php and I've ran into a problem. I'm trying to set a link to another php page within a dropdown list but no matter how I configure it the option won't direct to the page. Heres what I've tried.

```
<?php
$var1 = "DieRoller";
$var2 = "MISC TOOLS";
$type = "list";
?>
<select name="<?php echo $type;?>" id="<?php echo $type;?>">
<option value="1"><?php echo $var2;?></option>
<option value="DieRoller.php?page=DieRoller"><?php echo $var1;?></option>
</select>
```

My goal is to have a link directing to a new page within the dropdown list. Everything is within the same folder

Comment: are you trying to redirect the user when they select an option or when they submit a form? Generally you'd have `<form action="DieRoller.php"><select>...</select><button>Submit</button></form>` if you want to do this on submit. If you want to do it when they change the selected item (or outside of a form element), you'll need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You want when the user clicks on the option must redirect to the link right?

**So you must add an anchor tag than when clicking on it will redirect you**

```
<option>
 <a href="DieRoller.php?page=DieRoller"><?php echo $var1;?></a>
</option>
```